how to draw a beautiful regular triangular pyramid?
The six sides of a regular triangular pyramid must be equal
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);         
    \coordinate (B) at (3,0);         
    \coordinate (C) at (1.5,2.6);     
    \coordinate (D) at (1.5, 3.5);    


    \draw[thick] (A) -- (B);                
    \draw[dashed, thick] (A) -- (C);        
    \draw[dashed, thick] (B) -- (C);        

 
    \draw[thick] (A) -- (D);
    \draw[thick] (B) -- (D);
    \draw[dashed, thick] (C) -- (D);        

  
    \node at (A) [below] {A};
    \node at (B) [below] {B};
    \node at (C) [above left] {C};
    \node at (D) [above] {D};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Maybe have a look at the 3d TiKz library p.564 of the pgf manual

Maybe with asymptote https://asy.marris.fr/asymptote/Polyedres/index.html

thanks for your answer
